# How to mangle class names

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

How could I mangle class names like this (ES6)

```
export class MyClass{....}
```

using [UglifyJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es)? I've already played around enough with different mangle options and combinations given in the API but still, no avail. On google search, almost all of the time, the search produces the opposite: 'How to preserve class names'.Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It is just not possible because you would have to know what the class name has been replaced with so you could use that anywhere it is referenced to not break the code

Comment: You normally would not want to mangle a class name because something outside of your mangled code could still try to instantiate that class and would not be able to if it _were_ mangled.

Comment: @Intervalia uh... that's kind of the point